# Access home directory within spark task node

Tags: pyspark

Directory: `/home/hadoop/`

`module.py`

```
def incr(value):
    return int(value + 1)
```

`main.py`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

import sys
sys.path.append('/home/hadoop/')
import module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]], schema=['id', 'value'])
    df.show()

    print(module.incr(5)) #this works

    # this throws module not found error
    incr_udf = F.udf(lambda val: module.incr(val), T.IntegerType()) 
    df = df.withColumn('new_value', incr_udf('value'))
    df.show()
```

Spark task nodes do not have access to /home/hadoop/
How do I import module.py from within spark task nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are submitting the spark to yarn. the task will be progress launched by user 'yarn' in the worknode and will not have permission to access.
you can add **--py-files module.py** to your spark-submit command, then you want directly call the function module.py  by adding `from module import *` since they are all in the container now

Comment: I tried that, but the `spark-submit` is just stuck forever. Any idea?

Comment: we need to check the spark ui and executor log further...